# Hypersphere isometry?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, metric-spaces, inner-products

I will denote the $n-$sphere of radius $1$ centered at the origin as $\mathbb{S}^n$, so that
$$
\mathbb{S}^n = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\ : \ \|x\| = 1\}.
$$
I am stuck on the following problem...I'm not even sure where to begin. I'm not sure I understand the definition of $g$, and how we can extrapolate information about $g$ from that definition. Also, what would $\mathbb{S}_a^{n-1}$ look like as defined below?

We will treat $\mathbb{R}^n$ as sitting inside $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ as the set of points whose last coordinate is $0$. We then have $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ sitting inside $\mathbb{S}^n$ as the equatorial sub-sphere. Suppose $a \in \mathbb{S}^n$ and let $\mathbb{S}_a^{n-1}:= a^{\perp} \cap \mathbb{S}^n.$ Suppose that $g \in O(n+1)$ and $g(a) = e_{n+1}$. Suppose $f \in O(n+1)$ and $f(a)=a$, so $f$ maps $\mathbb{S}_a^{n-1}$ isometrically to itself.

$(a)$ Explain why $g$ maps $\mathbb{S}_a^{n-1}$ isometrically to $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.

$(b)$ Explain why $gfg^{-1} \in O(n)$ and is therefore an isometry of $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.

Comment: Have you made a sketch of the situation when $n = 2$? Are you happy with the facts that (i) If $a$ is a non-zero vector in $\mathbf{R}^{n+1}$, then $a^\perp$ is an $n$-dimensional subspace; (ii) Multiplication by an orthogonal matrix in $O(n+1)$ defines an isometry of $S^{n}$?

Comment: Alright, those points make sense. I'm pretty sure I understand what $\mathbb{S}_a^{n-1}$ looks like. But, could you help me understand what the definition of $g$ means?

Comment: Note that you don't have a definition of $g$, but a _condition_ satisfied by $g$. (There's an $O(n)$ worth of matrices in $O(n+1)$ sending $a$ to $e_{n+1}$.) Since $g$ is an orthogonal transformation, it maps $a^\perp$ to $e_{n+1}^\perp$, i.e., to $\mathbf{R}^n$, and it maps $S^n$ to itself. This should give (a) easily. For (b), show/note that $gfg^{-1}$ is orthogonal, and calculate $gfg^{-1}(e_{n+1})$.

Comment: I just worked out the details; thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(a)$ Let $x \in a^\perp$. Then $\langle x,a \rangle = 0$. Since $g$ is orthogonal, we also have $\langle g(x),g(a) \rangle = 0 \iff \langle g(x),e_{n+1} \rangle = 0$. Thus $g(x) \in e_{n+1}^\perp = \mathbb{R}^n$.

Now let $x \in \mathbb{S}_a^{n-1}$. Then the above condition holds, and also $\|g(x)\| = \|x\| = 1$. Hence $g(x) \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. Hence $g$ maps $\mathbb{S}_a^{n-1}$ isometrically to $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.

$(b)$ Since $g$ is orthogonal, $g^{-1}$ is also orthogonal. And since $gfg^{-1}$ is a composition of orthogonal matrices, it is also orthogonal. Note the following:
\begin{align*}
g^{-1}(e_{n+1}) & = a \\
fg^{-1}(e_{n+1}) & = f(a) = a \\
gfg^{-1}(e_{n+1}) & = g(a) = e_{n+1}.
\end{align*}
Since $gfg^{-1}(e_{n+1}) = e_{n+1}$, we conclude that if $x \in S^{n-1} = e_{n+1}^\perp \cap \mathbb{S}^n$, then $0 = \langle x, e_{n+1} \rangle$ $= \langle f(x), f(e_{n+1}) \rangle = \langle f(x), e_{n+1} \rangle$. Hence $x \in e_{n+1}^\perp$. But also $1 = \|x\| = \|f(x)\|$, so $x \in \mathbb{S}^n$. Thus we conclude that $x \in e_{n+1}^\perp \cap \mathbb{S}^n = S^{n-1}$, that is, $gfg^{-1}$ is an isometry of $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.